# Checking connectivity of a graph using a non-adjacency list in O(m) time

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity, big-o, depth-first-search

The question is as follows:

> We still know a number n, denoting the number of nodes in the graph.
> However, instead of being given the adjacency list of the graph, we
> are given a sorted "non-adjacency list." The non-adjacency list means
> there is no edge between the node and the nodes on the list, and if a
> node pair is not on the list, then there exists an edge. For example,
> if the sorted linked-list of node 3 is 1 -> 2 -> 10 -> NULL, it means
> that there are no edges between pairs: (3,1),(3,2), and (3,10), but
> all the other (3, j) pairs exist. Assume that there are totally m
> elements in the non-adjacency list and m > n, design an algorithm to
> check whether the given graph is connected in O(m) time.

Normally this would be a piece of cake, just modify DFS and run through to see if it's connected. But the O(m) portion is tripping me up. I've been trying for a while to reduce the time complexity and I'm stuck on how I can get it down to O(m).

Comment: This is not immediately clear from the description: are your given `N` "non-adjacency" lists (one for each node), but there is a total of `M` elements in all these lists?

Comment: Because otherwise, if there are `N` lists with `M` elements each, I don't think this is possible to solve in O(M). I thought that the "sorted list" condition could be used somehow, but, as it is stated that these are linked lists, you can't even binary search them efficiently.

Comment: Create a fully connected adjacency list. Iterate through every entry in the non-adjacency list O(m) and remove the corresponding entry from your adjacency list O(1), n times (depending on the list construction, thanks @Aivean...) I think you now have O(n+v) with taking more memory. I think this is a sketch the B- / C+ answer. I think you can likely do some sort of non-adjacency traversal, and which will be the "A" answer.